# How to deacivate related products on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, datafeed

I am working on wordpress,the plugins are :woocommerce,datafeedr api,and datefeedr product sets,I added some products from datafeedr also in woocommerce,now I want to deactivate the related product temporarily,I don t  went to remove them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress administration, not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
remove_action(
  'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',
  'woocommerce_output_related_products',
  20
);
```

If that didn't work, remove it and use this in **functions.php**:

```
add_filter(
  'woocommerce_related_products_args',
  '_remove_related_products',
  10
);

function _remove_related_products( $args ) {
  return array();
}
```

I hope this one work, if didn't, you change 10 to 20, 30 or ... until it works, I hope.

Comment: Oh, sorry, anywhere in your **functions.php** file.

Comment: Hi,it s me again,i try the solution but it s not working,i add it in  function.php in my themes,is this right,also i am working on staging,sorry i am new in this things,thanks

Comment: Thanks Mehdi,sorry for being late